# SQL index match to find duplicate data

Tags: sql, match

I have the following table

```
Code     Name    Task
aa       jones   DC
ab       dave    DC
aca      james   IF
aca      james   DC
ab       trevor  IF
aa       jones   IF
ag       francis DC
ag       francis IF
af       derek   SF
af       derek   DC
```

This is a very big table, above is just a quick example.

So, I would like some help finding the code and name that have completed a `IF` or `SF` task and a `DC` task.

I would like it to show where one person has touched both of these tasks. The hierarchy of the tasks is; it comes in as either a `SF` or `IF` then someone will do that, then off the back of that we receive a `DC` task, and I want the ones where it has been completed by the same person, with the same reference number.
I am able to do this in excel with an INDEX MATCH function, but this takes up a tremendous amount of calculation time due to the size of the table.

Comment: Name can do the same task more than once?

Comment: There is only one of each task associated with a code. So a code will have either "SF" or "IF" and a "DC"

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, my question was about if, for example, 'james' can do the task 'aca' only one time or more than one time

Comment: sorry, any task can only be done once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this is using `group by` with a `having`.  This is a flexible way of expressing these types of conditions:

```
select code, name
from table t
group by code, name
having sum(case when task = 'DC' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when task in ('IF', 'SF') then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of rows that meet the particular condition.  The first, for instance, counts the rows that match `'DC'` and takes only the `code, name` pairs that have at least one such match.

Comment: Hi Gordon, ignore my previous post. I tried your code and it works, this is awesome. Thank you so much

Comment: @Greylegface . . . You can delete your own comment by putting the mouse near the `edit` and clicking on the little `x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT code,name FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE task = 'DC' AND (task = 'IF' OR task = 'SF') GROUP BY name
```

try this query

Comment: can u tell me which database are you using and tell column type

Comment: You are making an logical query error: `task = 'DC' AND (task = 'IF' OR task = 'SF')` never evaluates to `true`. It does not depend on column type or database engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
select code,name from (select distinct code,name from table1 where task='SF' or task='IF') as temp1 inner join (select distinct code as code2,name as name2 from table1 where task='DC') as temp2 on code=code2,name=name2;
```

I'm assuming that you have the table in `table1`. The code constructs two tables `temp1` and `temp2`. `temp1` contains those codes and names which have been assigned SF and IF. `temp2` contains those codes and names which have been assigned DC. Finally, I join the two tables together to find code-name pairs in both tables. This is faster than in Excel because the database engine probably temporarily indexes the columns being joined on.

Actually, you can do this in Excel. You sort the table by code and name, then enter the following formulas (assuming "Code" is in `A1`):

```
D2=if(and(A2=A1,B2=B1,D1),true,or(C2="IF",C2="SF"))
E2=if(and(A2=A1,B2=B1,E1),true,C2="DC")
```

Select these two cells, and double-click the fill-handle (the little square at the bottom right of the selection). Then, with the two columns selected, copy, and then "Paste Special..." > "Values". Then, filter (Alt-D-F-F) for the rows with values in columns D and E being both true. That is the result you want. Select these rows and copy to a new sheet if desired.

Alternatively, you can follow the SQL "group by" solution given by Gordon, so that you do not need to sort: Create two new columns like the above, but:

```
D1: "D"
E1: "E"
D2=if(or(C2="IF",C2="SF"),1,0)
E2=if(C2="DC",1,0)
```

Then, "Insert" > "PivotTable", drag "Code" and "Name" to be row labels. Drag "D" to be under Values, click on it, "Value Field Settings...", and then select "Max". Do the same for "E", and then the rows with 1 in both D and E will be the result you want.

Comment: Hi,

Can I just ask. In the sql I am trying to run it but it cannot find the "name2" column, as there isnt a name2 column in the table, which is obvious. Could you explain how to overcome this please?

I understand the majority of the code apart from the last part "on name=name2"..

thank you

Comment: Hi, Thanks for writing this very helpful post. I haev used Gordons reply and that is working in sql and pulls the relevant data. I have then used a pivto table to sort the data so it can be sliced. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Sorry for the error. I edited the code to correct it. However, I have to admit that Gordon's query might be actually more efficient than this. It will be nice to know which performs faster.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff's query can be made easier under the hypothesys that `IF` and `SF` are synonym and cannot be both present for the same Code-Name couple, as the data provided by the OP suggests

```
SELECT code, name
FROM   table t
GROUP BY code, name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN task IN ('IF', 'SF', 'DC') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2;
```